# Check for typos, slang, and code formatting issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

How is the output of the code **Hello World!**.

```
print("\110\145\154\154\157\40\127\157\162\154\144\41")
```

output: `Hello World!`

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: Title and the question  are very different.  :\

Answer (score 1):

According to the list of escape sequence in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), `\ooo` represents a character with octal value `ooo`

So if we consider the first character `\110`, this is a character with octal value `110` , or integer value of `72`, which is `H` as shown below

```
In [25]: print('\110')                                                                                                                                               
H

In [26]: chr(0o110)                                                                                                                                                  
Out[26]: 'H'

In [27]: chr(72)                                                                                                                                                     
Out[27]: 'H'

In [28]: 0o110 == 72                                                                                                                                                 
Out[28]: True
```

Similarly other characters can be argued for and the reason behind the code printing `Hello World` can be understood

---

Answer (score 0):

I took this image from this [IBM® IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ioaq100/ascii_table_appendix.htm) and I highlighted some characters which need to print `Hello World!`.

[image: highlighted text to recognized 'Hello World!']

So you are printing ASCII characters from octal value. How do we know those are Octals or not? Check the below table (took it from [rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Quotes.html) and also they were provided some examples and you can find it from [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) too),

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| \n         |  newline                                             |
| \r         |  carriage return                                     |
| \t         |  tab                                                 |
| \b         |  backspace                                           |
| \a         |  alert (bell)                                        |
| \f         |  form feed                                           |
| \v         |  vertical tab                                        |
| \\         |  backslash \                                         |
| \'         |  ASCII apostrophe '                                  |
| \"         |  ASCII quotation mark "                              |
| \`         |  ASCII grave accent (backtick) `                     |
| \nnn       |  character with given octal code (1, 2 or 3 digits)  |
| \xnn       |  character with given hex code (1 or 2 hex digits)   |
| \unnnn     |  Unicode character with given code (1--4 hex digits) |
| \Unnnnnnnn |  Unicode character with given code (1--8 hex digits) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You provided two or three digits after each and every backlashes(`\`), according to `\nnn` format from the above table it's a Octal value.

```
'H' --> 110
'e' --> 145
'l' --> 154
'l' --> 154
'o' --> 157
' ' --> 40
'W' --> 127
'o' --> 157
'r' --> 162
'l' --> 154
'd' --> 144
'!' --> 41
```

These are the octal value you used to print `Hello World!` and also you can print it from hexadecimal values too.

```py
>>> print("\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21")  # \xnn format
Hello World!
```